# Unable to reload filtered data in same table on button click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:
        
                    
                    Status
                    
                        Choose a Status
            Live</option>
                        Scheduled</option>
                        Expired</option>
                        Saved</option> -->
                    
                
            
            
                
                    Name

```
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block button-red" style="margin-top:1em;"  class="form-control" 
                        ng-click="applySearchFilter()">filter</button>
            </div>
        </div> 


    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped" style="  text-align: center;">


        <tr ng-repeat="product in $data"  ng-hide="product.excludedByFilter">**strong text**
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.applySearchFilter = function() {
        var nameFilter = $scope.filters.title;
        var statusFilter = $scope.filters.status.name;

        var showAll = 0 === nameFilter.length && 0 === statusFilter.length;

     //   $scope.tableParams = $filter(statusFilter)($scope.tableParams, tableParams);
        angular.forEach($data, function(product) {
            if (showAll) {
                product.excludedByFilter = false;
                console.log("value in if::::"+product.title);

            } else {
                console.log("value is::::"+product.title);
                product.excludedByFilter = (product.title.indexOf(nameFilter) === -1) 
                                        || ($scope.data.status.indexOf(statusFilter) === -1) ;
            }
        });
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    }

 $scope.$watch("applySearchFilter", function () {
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    });
```

i am trying to show filtered data on same ng-table by clicking on filter button